# MySQL LIKE for two words

Tags: mysql

What would be the right SQL statement so that when I search two words, like for example 'text field' in a text box, it will return all results that has 'text' and 'field' in it using the LIKE statement?
I cant find the right terms to make a search.

EDIT :  If possible, I want to make it dynamic. Like if a user search 5 words, all 5 words would be in the Like statement. I am trying to achieve a statement
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE search (LIKE %searchterm1%) OR (LIKE %searchterm2%) OR (LIKE %searchterm3%)` ....

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your additional information.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 LIKE '%text%' AND column1 LIKE '%field%')
```

To allow the user to input multiple words, firstly take a look at the problems of [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), but assuming you're using PHP you can explode an input string and implode the resulting array, like this;

```
$values = explode(" ", $input); // delimiter is a space
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 LIKE '%" . implode("%' AND column1 LIKE '%",$values) . "%')";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The the words are unordered use a standard [logical conjunction (aka AND)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)

```
LIKE '%word1%' AND LIKE '%word2%'
```

If the words are ordered use an implicit conjunction in the search term itself

```
LIKE '%word1%word2%'
```

Modify the like wildcards (and quotes) as needed; also consider if [a full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) might be more appropriate.